# How do add padding bigger than p-5 for certain screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a webpage that needs to be build responsively.

Here is a snippet of the section in question:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row p-3 p-lg-5">
        <div class="col">
            Some text
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            More text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the row to have a padding of 3 when on mobile devices and a padding of 20% when on desktop devices. I also need the max width of the row to be 70% when on desktop and 100% when on mobile.

How do I achieve this with bootstrap-5?

Comment: You either recompile `bootstrap` and create new classes (something like `p-20%`) or simply make your own custom class that does what you need without touching `bootstrap`.

Comment: @ThS if I add my custom class like p-20% and recompile, will it still work with the screen sizes like p-lg-p20

Comment: You may take a look at how to customize `bootstrap` the way you want through their [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/).

Answer (score 0):

you can find your solution here at bootstrap official page [Bootstrap Spacing Classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, xl, and xxl.

Where property is one of:

m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding
Where sides is one of:

t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
s - (start) for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL
e - (end) for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-left in RTL
x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
Where size is one of:

0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto